# view/motionEvent cannot be resolved to a variable swipe

Tags: android, eclipse, variables, view, motionevent

I have got this code from another stackoverflow question:

```
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureListener());

    public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent event) {
        super.onTouch(view, motionEvent);
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffY > 0) {
                            onSwipeBottom();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeTop();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public void onSwipeRight() {
    }

    public void onSwipeLeft() {
    }

    public void onSwipeTop() {
    }

    public void onSwipeBottom() {
    }
}
```

After I paste the code into eclipse, I get error on  super.onTouch(view, motionEvent); .
The compiler compliance level is set to 1.6 if that helps you.
I tried restarting eclipse, deleting and importing the project but without success.
Thanks and a happy new year!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variables don't match:

```
//  You need to use these names   *                    *****
public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent event) {
    super.onTouch(v, event);
```

But you are implementing OnTouchListener so really this line does nothing. You can remove it.

Comment: I get this error after switching the codes:The method onTouch(View,MotionEvent) is undefinited for the type Object. Thanks for trying Sam!

Comment: @Sam This still doesn't work for me, I get the same error as user1930518 had.